# 2 local folders, each containing a different branch of the same repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm have a repository in Bitbucket and I use Altassian SourceTree to work with it.

Is it possible to have two folders for two branches of the same repository?

I have found this [answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/161665/is-it-possible-to-have-2-local-folders-each-containing-a-different-branch-of-the-same-repository), but I don't understand what to do and I'm bit afraid of if 'I do evil' and I lost my repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily by following these steps:

1. Clone your repo and check out your first branch you want
2. Clone your repo again, but change the `Destination Path` to a different local folder, and check out your second branch you want

---

**Q:** But...Can I still use SourceTree in both?

**A:** Yes you can. Each cloned repo will be visible in a list on the left side.
If you open both you get two tabs (one for each) and you can switch there between the local repos (which acces to the same remote repo)

In this picture I cloned the repo twice one for the `master` branch and one for the `develop` branch *(but I checked out the develop twice, but I think you can understand the principle)*:

[image]

**Note:** the changes you made in your first local repo can only be seen in your second local repo after pushing the changes to your remote repo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But...Can I still use SourceTree with both?